# Status bar rotates but application does not, on iPhone- works fine on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, rotation

Long time lurker, always tried very hard to search and have found many answers this way.  This is the first time I have found nothing that fixes my problem.  This is also my first solo app, as I am a new developer.

I have two devices- an iOS 8.1 iPhone 6, and an iOS 7 iPad Mini Retina 2.

I am building my first iOS app.  It uses storyboards for a UITabBarController with three tabs, each of which contains a UINavigationController and a custom sub view controller (such as a subclass of tabbarcontroller or collectionviewcontroller).

Under Deployment Info:
Deployment Target is set to 7.0 and Universal.  iPhone and iPad both use the MainStoryboard main interface, with all four Device Orientations checked for both.

My AppDelegate starts with:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UITabBarController *initViewController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootTabBarController"];

NSLog(@"%d %d",initViewController.shouldAutorotate,initViewController.shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods);

[self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
```

Note the NSLog; it prints "1 0".

So from what I can see- the tab bar should auto rotate.

On my iPhone, when I turn the device sideways, the status bar on the top rotates- but the content remains upright.  If I hit the Home button and switch back to the app while holding it sideways, everything goes wonky- the content rotates but doesn't rearrange the layout, so it remains vertical, and thus gets cut off and there's a big black section on the side.

On my iPad, though- everything works fine!  The application rotates as expected and resizes itself.

What am I doing wrong here?  Thank you tremendously for any help.

Comment: Why are you programmatically loading the storyboard?  If there's no specific need to do that, I'd suggest just using the template app delegate code.  Better yet, create a completely new, fresh project and just copy over your storyboard. It won't necessarily make sense, but... I bet it will work! :-)

Comment: Sorry for responding so late!  I saw your comment and tried erasing all the code in the app delegate and it worked, thank you so much!

I had originally started the app loading everything programmatically and then decided to try out a storyboard.  I wasn't sure how to make the "switch" so I replaced my code with one manually loading the storyboard, not realizing it would work fine if I simply removed all the code.  Not sure why that broke rotation!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry- I'm new here- how do I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: Oh, you can't accept comments.  But, I pasted it into an actual answer, so you can accept that. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you programmatically loading the storyboard? If there's no specific need to do that, I'd suggest just using the template app delegate code. Better yet, create a completely new, fresh project and just copy over your storyboard. It won't necessarily make sense, but... I bet it will work!